# VIM:  Don't pause after `make`

Tags: vim, make

How can I make it so that I don't have to press the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key every time I run `:make` in VIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefixing commands with `:silent` will suppress their output, e.g. `:silent make`. For quick access your can define a new command by putting the following in your .vimrc:

```
command Smake silent make
```

Other solutions here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts

Answer (score 2):

Yo @WakiMiko, that's not what the OP wants. He still wants to see the output, only without the annoying prompts. The answer is `set nomore` cause once you set it, the prompts will be no more.(hehe)